# What is the "Horn" (Qeren, קֶ֨רֶן) God raised in Psalm 148:14?

Tags: psalms, hebrew-bible

In Psalm 148, we are told in verse 14 that God raised a Horn for His people.

Tehillim / Psalms 148:14 [MT]

> "And He raised [a] Horn for His people" ( וַיָּ֚רֶם קֶ֨רֶן לְעַמּ֡וֹ )

**What is the "Horn" (Qeren, קֶ֨רֶן) God raised, and what does It do?**

Answer (score 2):

Horns are often used in the Bible to symbolize power, strength, authority, and victory.

> Deuteronomy 33:16b Let all these rest on the head of Joseph,
> on the brow of the prince among his brothers.
> 17In majesty he is like a firstborn bull;
> his horns are the **horns** of a wild ox.
> With them he will **gore** the nations,
> even those at the ends of the earth.

It is the power to conquer.

> Psalm 148:14 And he has raised up for his people a horn,
> the praise of **all** his faithful servants

Ultimately, it has been fulfilled in Jesus Christ, God's most faithful servant, and Christianity has spread all over the world.